# "typeclass-constrained type variable when beta reducing" use case

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and there is a logic I don't understand when we reduce this expression :

```
Prelude> let f :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a; f = undefined
Prelude> :t f 1 2
f 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
```

I don't understand why we get constrained with Num, I would have expected more something like :

```
`f 1 2 :: Ord a => a`
```

Comment: Because you partially applied it with `1`, so Haskell sees that `1 :: a`, and a number literal has `Num a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *partially apply* `f` with `f 1 2`. So that means that `1 :: a`, and `2 :: b`.

Now a number literal (like `1`, `42`, `14.25`) always is a type of the `Num` typeclass. Indeed:

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num t => t
```

It is not certain at this point what type (since it can be an `Int`, `Integral`, `Float`, etc.). But it thus means that we now have constraint the type of `a` further, so the result should also have that type constraint.

If we had used a `Char`, then `a` would have been a `Char`:

```
Prelude> :t f 'a' 2
f 'a' 2 :: Char
```